# How to center this search form?

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying center the search bar so when people zoom out it wont go to the left of the page instead adjust its self to be in the center, i tried adding `<center>` before the form and it doesn't work. what could i do so the search form is always in the center ?

```
<div class="Nav">
   <a href="../index"><img src="/img/putlockermedia_logo.png" /></a>
   <form action='/search.php' method='GET'> <!-- start of search bar -->
        <input id='searchbar' type='text' name='search' placeholder="search for movies & tv shows" maxlength="50" required />
        <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' disabled />
   </form>
   <script>
      document.getElementById('searchbar').oninput = function() {
      document.getElementById('submit').disabled = !this.value.trim();
   }
   </script> <!-- end of search bar -->
   <div class="Navbuttons">
     <a href="../shows"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="shows" /></a>
     <a href="../movies"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="movies" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
<style>

.nav
{
    width:100%;
    background: #999;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    min-width: 960px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use `<center>`, as it's not supported in HTML5 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using nav in any class= attribute in your tags.
Besides remembering that detail, try something like:

```
<div class="myCenter">
    <form action='/search.php' method='GET'> <!-- start of search bar -->
        <input id='searchbar' type='text' name='search' placeholder="search for movies & tv shows" maxlength="50" required />
        <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' disabled />
    </form>
</div>
```

Spoiler: adding a wrapping div with a new class, to the form tag.
With class:

```
div.myCenter { text-align: center }
div.myCenter form { text-align: left } //optional, if you don't want to see your elements as centered
```

<center> tag is deprecated as is God.